# Filter/Reject Array of strings against multiple values using underscore

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

I'd like to `_.filter` or `_.reject` the `cities` array using the `filters` array using underscore.

```
var cities = ['USA/Aberdeen', 'USA/Abilene', 'USA/Akron', 'USA/Albany', 'USA/Albuquerque', 'China/Guangzhou', 'China/Fuzhou', 'China/Beijing', 'China/Baotou', 'China/Hohhot' ... ]
var filters = ['Akron', 'Albuquerque', 'Fuzhou', 'Baotou'];
```

My progress so far:

```
var filterList;

if (reject) {
    filterList = angular.copy(cities);
    _.each(filters, (filter) => {
        filterList = _.reject(filterList, (city) => city.indexOf(filter) !== -1);
    });
} else {
    filterList = [];
    _.each(filters, (filter) => {
        filterList.push(_.filter(cities, (city) => city.indexOf(filter) !== -1));
    });
}

filterList = _.flatten(filterList);

return filterList;
```

I'd like to DRY this up and use a more functional approach to achieve this if possible?

Comment: return filters.map(el=>"USA/"+el);

Comment: Why does the formatting of the city differ between `cities` and `filters`? You could greatly simplify your code if only that weren't the case.

Comment: The `filters` are user input. The `cities` are data from API. So, I'm trying to accommodate more flexible filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using vanilla JavaScript here (some() and filter()) but I hope you get the idea:

```
const isValidCity = city => filters.some(filter => city.indexOf(filter) > -1)

const filteredCities = cities.filter(isValidCity)
```

Please note that this is a loop over a loop. So the time complexity is O(n * m) here.

Comment: I don't quite follow this approach? I keep getting `filteredCities === cities`

Comment: Sorry, fixed the indexOf.

Comment: Would be awesome if you could give a little explanation as to how you got here? Your thought process? Thanks again dude :)

Comment: The complexity is actually `O(m * n)` (worst case, something better average case because of short-circuiting.)

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat more functional version using Underscore might look like this:

```
const cities = ['USA/Aberdeen', 'USA/Abilene', 'USA/Akron', 'USA/Albany', 
                'USA/Albuquerque', 'China/Guangzhou', 'China/Fuzhou',
                'China/Beijing', 'China/Baotou', 'China/Hohhot']
const filters = ['Akron', 'Albuquerque', 'Fuzhou', 'Baotou'];

var inList = names => value => _.any(names, name => value.indexOf(name) > -1);

_.filter(cities, inList(filters));
//=> ["USA/Akron", "USA/Albuquerque", "China/Fuzhou", "China/Baotou"]

_.reject(cities, inList(filters));
//=> ["USA/Aberdeen", "USA/Abilene", "USA/Albany", 
//    "China/Guangzhou", "China/Beijing", "China/Hohhot"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example all city keys share the same pattern: `country` + `/` + `city`. Your filters are all an exact match to the `city` part of these names.

If this is a certainty in your data *(which it probably isn't...)*, you could reduce the number of loops your code makes by creating a `Map` or `object` that stores each city per filter entry:

- Create an object with an entry for each city name
- Make the `key` the part that you want the filter to match
- Make the `value` the original name
- Loop through the `filters` and return the name at each key.

This approach always requires *one* loop through the data and *one* loop through the filters. For small array sizes, you won't notice a performance difference. When one of the arrays has length 1, you'll also not notice any differences.

Again, note that this only works if there's a constant relation between your filters and cities.

```js
var cities = ['USA/Aberdeen', 'USA/Abilene', 'USA/Akron', 'USA/Albany', 'USA/Albuquerque', 'China/Guangzhou', 'China/Fuzhou', 'China/Beijing', 'China/Baotou', 'China/Hohhot' ]
var filters = ['Akron', 'Albuquerque', 'Fuzhou', 'Baotou'];

const makeMap = (arr, getKey) => arr.reduce(
  (map, x) => Object.assign(map, {
    [getKey(x)]: x
  }), {}
);

const getProp = obj => k => obj[k];
const getKeys = (obj, keys) => keys.map(getProp(obj));

// Takes the part after the "/"
const cityKey = c => c.match(/\/(.*)/)[1];
const cityMap = makeMap(cities, cityKey);

const results = getKeys(cityMap, filters);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using AngularJS, you could utilize the built-in filter functionality. Assuming both the cities and filters array exist on your controller and you're displaying the cities array using `ng-repeat`, you could have something like this on your controller:

```
function cityFilter(city) {
    var cityName = city.split('/')[1];
    if (reject) {
        return filters.indexOf(cityName) === -1;
    } else {
        return filters.indexOf(cityName) > -1;
    }
}
```

And then in your template, you'd do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="city in cities | filter : cityFilter"></div>
```

Of course you'd have to modify your syntax a bit depending on your code style (for example, whether you use `$scope` or `controllerAs`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a function in a service, not using ng-repeat. Using an angular filter is also not an option.